# Show nested fragment on screen rotation without showing parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

When rotating the screen my nested fragment is shown but for some brief moments, the parent fragment is also shown.

I have my MainActivity that has a `FrameLayout` with ID `activity_base_container`.

I'm doing this when my activity starts:

```
Fragment initialFragment = getInitialFragment();
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.activity_base_container, initialFragment, initialFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
        .commit();
```

That `initialFragment` initial fragment is responsible to check some conditions and depending them will launch one of two possible fragments:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_base_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
```

Lets assume it launches `FragmentF` (whit a root `FrameLayout` with id `fragment_f_root`). This fragments layout has a set of options. When the user clicks one of those options, the corresponding fragment is created and is launched like this:

```
//The example here is an option that displays a google map.
fragment = FragmentMapMultipleActivity.newInstance();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.fragment_f_root, fragment)
      .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
      .commit();
```

At this point all is working as expected. The problem is when I rotate the screen. `FragmentF` appears briefly and then immediately `FragmentMapMultipleActivity`, the nested fragment, appears.

Is it possible after rotating the screen show only the nested fragment or I should change my "architecture" to something else?

Comment: just a thought: in `FragmentF`, you should use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of "normal" one. Also, make sure you _really_ want to do `addToBackStack` for nested fragment.    To show only nested fragment on the landscape, I'd create a special layout for landscape, where `R.id.fragment_f_root` takes the whole screen (or, just expand it once orientation changed). Though, I'm not sure that it answering your question

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov Thanks. In `FragmentF` I'm using `getChildFragmentManager()`. From my research I think I will change my implementation so I do not use nested fragments

Comment: In my humble opinion, I barely can come up with any good reasoning to use nested fragments anywhere apart from `ViewPager`. Custom Views reduce comlexity here and keeping lifecycle much more predictable.

Comment: Yes. I'm realizing that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should change my "architecture" to something else?

Probably, you *should*.
The brightest Android-minds from Square are even advocating to avoid simple fragments everywhere it's possible: [Advocating Against Android Fragments](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html)

Nested fragemnts, in its turn, increase complexity exponentially. The only good pattern of using them I've seen so far is `ViewPager` with it's `FragmentPagerAdapter`. In majority of other cases, **consider using Custom Views** instead.
It keeps your app's lifecycle cleaner and more predictable.

I don't think you can do much with this blinking you see, apart from:

- [`setRetainInstance(true)`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject) and avoid full re-creation of the Fragment in Activity, so you keep you fragment's data during change of the configuration (and then pass same retained fragment to the fragment manager)
- keeping layouts as lightweight as possible
- avoid re-creation of already initialized variables
- keep `onViewCreate()` as lightweight as possible

Good luck!